# What is the height of a person who is eight ratnis in stature?

Tags: mahabharata

Karna is described to have 8 ratnis by Lord Krishna to Arjuna?

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08072.htm

> Endued with might, he resembles a lion in the formation of his body. **He is eight ratnis in stature.**

How tall is a person who is 8 ratnis in stature?

How much is a ratni?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/ratni). One ratni = the length of 21 angula parvas. So we can get an idea roughly.

Comment: But the length of the angula parvas is not a fixed distance, it can change from person to person. And specially if humans of previous Yugas are taller then they used to have larger angula parvas. So this makes the definition somewhat ambiguous.